# Como desabilitar a resolução de nomes de domínio (hostnames) da JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Uma aplicação está tentando acessar um EJB remoto. Independente se a configuração usa o endereço `servidor.empresa.com.br` ou um IP para acessar o serviço, ocorre um erro:

```
weblogic.utils.NestedError: This address was valid earlier, but now we get: .
    at weblogic.rjvm.JVMID.address(JVMID.java:565)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.record(RJVMManager.java:153)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMManager.java:292)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemote(RJVMManager.java:139)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManagerServer.handleIdentifyResponse(ConnectionManager
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.net.UnknownHostException: servidor
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1158)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:970)
    at weblogic.rjvm.JVMID.address(JVMID.java:558)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Ao que parece, independente do hostname e do IP a JVM está fazendo uma consulta ao DNS e, por alguma razão, está ignorando o `.empresa.com.br`, usando apenas o nome do servidor.

Existe algum meio de dizer à JVM *"esqueça o DNS, use apenas o IP!"*?

Observações:

- Uma alternativa proposta em alguns fóruns é editar `hosts` (ambiente windows) apontando o `servidor` (sem o `.empresa.com.br` para o respectivo IP, mas me parece mais uma gambiarra
- Versão da JDK: 1.6
- Versão do Weblogic: 10

Comment: Por acaso o sistema operacional envolvido é Linux?

Comment: Pela descrição, a aplicação parece estar com bug, tentando consultar com o endereço errado (ignorando `.empresa.com.br`). Não seria melhor consertar esse problema?

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Windows XP (máquina de desenvolvimento).

Comment: @elias Não é bug da aplicação, ela funciona em outros ambientes e, como eu expliquei, mesmo passando o IP não funciona. O endereço é passado diretamente para o `InitialContext` assim: `prop.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL , providerURL ); InitialContext ic = new InitialContext( prop ); `

Comment: No momento, o mais próximo que eu vejo, seria tentar alguma modificação com [DNS_URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#DNS_URL). Mas não acredito que seja isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisando pela mensagem de erro:

> This address was valid earlier, but now we get ...

É perceptível que ela só ocorre com quem usa Weblogic em algum tipo de ambiente específico, geralmente corporativo com firewalls e proxies.

Não há muitos resultados para o erro e nenhum dos que existem apontam uma causa ou solução específica, a não ser um *workaround* que é adicionar o nome do servidor sem o seu domínio ao arquivos "hosts" do sistema operacional:

- Windows: `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Outros: `/etc/drivers`

Answer (score 2):

Verifique duas coisas:

Adiciona no **hosts** da máquina o IP e nome, e desablita o verifcation name do servidor.

Se for um server do domínio coloque no server:  **ServerName->ServerStart->Arguments** 
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true

Se for o AdminServer, tem que ser no script SetDomainEnv.sh:  **JAVA_OPTIONS="Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true"**
**Export JAVA_OPTIONS**

Espero ter ajudado ;)